# Multiple values in custom variables for visitor lifetime

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to store multiple values in custom variables for visitor lifetime and I'm finding the documentation a little bit ambiguous on how overwriting works. So say on request 1 I set:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Visitor-Type", "Member", 1]);
```

and in a separate page view I set:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Gender", "Male", 1]);
```

Will future sessions remember both "Visitor-Type" and "Gender", or will "Gender" be the only one remembered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of the `_setCustomVar` call determines the scope of your variable as described in http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples In your example, they are set to 1 which translates as "Visitor-level" and will be persisted in a per-visitor cookie so this should work across requests.

However, it seems that you need to vary the second parameter -- the "slot" -- in order for these variables to work properly. If you write two variables to the same slot, they will override each other as is evidenced by inspecting your cookies.

e.g.

```js
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Gender", "Male", 1]);
document.cookie;
// => "...1=Gender=Male=1"

_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Visitor-Type", "Member", 1]);
document.cookie;
// => "...1=Visitor-Type=Member=1"
```

From the documentation, it seems that you can only track up to 5 custom variables.